# Is there any way to subdivide the faces going around the edge of this so that the curve is smoother?

Tags: modeling

**Butterfly knife trainer**

[image: Butterfly knife trainer]

The edge on this trainer butterfly knife model that I'm making is very rough (obviously).

However is there any way to add more subdivisions so as to smooth it out without using the smooth button? If not, then what is the best way? Thanks and have a great day!:D

Comment: Have you tried selecting the required faces in edit mode and subdividing them with W-key menu?

Comment: Tried but it didnt work

Comment: I found out how though I just marked the edges as sharp and then added a subdivide modifier and edge split modifier

Answer (score 1):

First of, you should recalculate normals that seem to be going inwards instead of outwards (notice the slight blueish tint instead of gray)
[image: First of, you should recalculate normals that seem to be going inwards instead of outwards (notice the slight blueish tint instead of gray)]

This is how correct normals look.
[image: This is how correct normals look.]

Next up is to make the mesh more smooth so press Ctrl+F and shade smooth in Edit mode (or can be done in the T panel in object mode aswell)
[image: Next up is to make the mesh more smooth so press Ctrl+F and shade smooth in Edit mode (or can be done in the T panel in object mode aswell)]

Without any other work whatsoever the mesh looks... uh.. ugly
[image: Without any other work whatsoever the mesh looks... uh.. ugly]

However only by adding a correctly set up bevel modifier, you get very good results with not much more geometry.
[image: However only by adding a correctly set up bevel modifier, you get very good results with not much more geometry.]

This is the bevel modifier of the above, please note that Width is subject to object size and obviously this knife would be a bit too large^^
[image: This is the bevel modifier of the above, please note that Width is subject to object size and obviously this knife would be a bit too large^^]

This is how the wireframe of the above looks.
[image: This is how the wireframe of the above looks.]

Alternatively you can also get visibly beveled (not rounded) edges by using only 1 segment in Bevel and turning Auto Smooth on at about 30-60 degrees. (notice I have profile 0 here and that is not necessary, it can be the default 0.5 because at 1 segment setting the profile doesn't play a role)
[image: Alternatively you can also get visibly beveled (not rounded) edges by using only 1 segment in Bevel and turning Auto Smooth on at about 30-60 degrees.]

This is the modifier setup of the above.
[image: This is the modifier setup of the above.]

And this is wireframe of the above.
[image: And this is wireframe of the above.]

Comment: Damn dude! thank you very much, I figured it out for a while but I'll definitely do this when I need to!

Comment: Also, is there any way to clean up the smooth shading without adding bevels?